# MySQL adds 2, unless I echo the variable in which case it adds only 1

Tags: php, mysql

please excuse the terrible title!

I have the following line of code:

```
$this->sql->mysqli->query(
    "UPDATE `threads` SET `views` = `views` + 1
    WHERE `id` = '".$this->thread['id']."'
");
```

One would expect this to add + 1 to views right? Well it doesn't. It adds 2!

This isn't any kind of loop or anything.

Anyway, I try this to fix it..

```
$views = $this->thread['views']++;      
$this->sql->mysqli->query(
    "UPDATE `threads` SET `views` = '".$views."'
    WHERE `id` = '".$this->thread['id']."'"
);
```

Again no luck, it still adds 2!

Trying to debug further...

```
$views = $this->thread['views']++;      
$this->sql->mysqli->query(
    "UPDATE `threads` SET `views` = '".$views."'
    WHERE `id` = '".$this->thread['id']."'"
);
echo $views;
```

With the code above, `$views` echos exactly what it should do and the row updates exactly how it should! The echo makes it work, I have no idea why and I don't want the echo.

Can't get to the problem is this, I feel like someone is taking the piss.

Regards

Mic

Edit: It turns out that it doesn't matter what is being echoed below version 1 above, it makes it work, but not without the echo

**Edit in response to brian and extra clarification:**

The follow code makes `views` add TWICE. (i.e., adds 2)

```
$this->sql->mysqli->query(
    "UPDATE `threads` SET `views` = `views` + 1
    WHERE `id` = '".$this->thread['id']."'"
);
```

The following code...

```
$this->sql->mysqli->query(
    "UPDATE `threads` SET `views` = `views` + 1
    WHERE `id` = '".$this->thread['id']."'"
);
echo 'foo';
```

- echos 'foo' ONCE and
- adds 1 to view (ie works properly)

Comment: I don't see how the first version could add 2 instead of 1... if it's not called two times...

Comment: Thats what I thought. To prove that its not called twice adding `echo '1';` below would echo twice if something like this was going on. Yet it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the cause but you are using the ++ operator wrong. it is used simply as: $i++ , without assigning it back to itself as you did: $i = $i++ ;

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu this still adds twice...
    $this->thread['views']++; 
    $this->sql->mysqli->query(
        "UPDATE `threads` SET `views` = ".$this->thread['views']."
        WHERE `id` = '".$this->thread['id']."'"
       );

Comment: You sure the variable isn't a duplicate? maybe in an include or something? or check your mysql

Comment: If you manually run that query on the database through phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench or something, you'll find that it does exactly what you want. It's not the SQL, it's something in your code. You're addressing the query method via `$this->sql->mysqli` so perhaps you should check with your database class (whatever the `sql` portion is), because there's likely something in there calling the query twice.

Comment: or maybe you set the views accidentally to auto increment

Comment: @LeventeNagy I'm pretty sure, and if that was the case why would echoing stuff change anything? Also why wouldn't getting rid of the variable and making it `views = views + 1` work, were that the case.

Comment: Thats why i asked the auto increment in your db, when you echo the variable yes thats 1, but if your column is auto increment it will add an extra 1

Comment: @Brian `mysqli` is the mysqli class, thus mysqli will query it straight away, nothing to do with me.

Comment: @LeventeNagy Nope view is just an int(225), default 0. I may not have explained myself, when I echo the variable the query works correctly. If I don't then it doesn't.

Comment: The "update threads set views=views+1 where id=1" query should work. Perhaps there is a trigger in mysql that auto-updates again ?

Comment: The echo should have nothing to do with your query running correctly. Additionally, that query will only add 1 to the table unless there's a trigger or auto_increment or something else at play on the DB side as people have mentioned. To prove that, add `echo 'foo';` under your 1st query. See how many times 'foo' echos out. Then check your database. You should still see the same result you've been seeing.

Comment: @Brian please refer to the added section in the question. I know it shouldn't effect it, but it does.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the previous value to a variable, and then making a new variable that equals the previous variable + 1? I.e. $oldValue = x; $newValue = $oldValue + 1; After that, just add $newValue into your query and see if it works.

Comment: echo'ing something after a query should have no change to the query, UNLESS it's stopping a loop somehow.   Can you post your entire <? to ?> code of this page?

Comment: What @briansol said is correct. The echo statement can physically have no effect on the query running or not running. Most likely you have something in your code that is stopping because an echo was made. Perhaps a redirect or something that can't occur because output was made. If you replace your `echo` line with `die( 'foo' );` you should see the output, and only get 1 increment in your database. Alternatively, add an `exit;` after your `echo` line and you'll likely see the same result. Proving again that this is not related to the query, or the echo, but rather something else in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

So after much detailing and agony I've found the source of this error.

I noticed it worked fine on my live website environment and but not in development. Surely an error with the server somehow? But nope - the error comes with the browser.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="" />
```

By failing to set a favicon image but having the empty tag, Chrome and Firefox (but not IE in my case however - reading around the internet the characteristics of each browser has varied) the browser loaded the page twice looking for it.

It also seems to do this for any `src=""` (such as on an image tag) attribute left empty.

**Why did the echo fix it?**

By far this was the most bizarre feature of this error. I can only theorise that it is due to the echo being made outside of any valid markup (before any `<html>` declaration) and thus the browser parsed the webpage differently.

**$_POST**

The final point of confusion was this did not happen during a post request, obviously Chrome does not try twice if POST data is sent.